# getting "530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first." error when sending mail via netcat

Tags: smtp, netcat

I'm trying to send an email with netcat, this is what i get:

```
****-MacBook-Pro:~ ***$ nc smtp.gmail.com 25
220 mx.google.com ESMTP h8sm66301168eew.16 - gsmtp
Helo gmail.com
250 mx.google.com at your service
MAIL FROM: <******@gmail.com>
530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first. h8sm66301168eew.16 - gsmtp
```

what is STARTTLS command and what do i need to do with it?

Answer (score 9):

STARTTLS is an extension to plain text communication protocols, which offers a way to upgrade a plain text connection to an encrypted (TLS or SSL) connection instead of using a separate port for encrypted communication.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/STARTTLS

The smtp server is saying it won't accept plain text connections.

Comment: so what are the solutions?

Comment: @mgPePe There are no solutions for this question. You cannot send a mail to that server using netcat because of the encryption requirement.

Comment: well, I had that problem with EC2 and CakePHP and it turned out I had to add `ssl://` to the host to make it work.

Answer (score -2):

You basicaly just need to specify that you're using TLS.

Answer (score -3):

Use EHLO instead of HELO. This will start 250-STARTTLS.